# How to separate ie hacks code from main scss file

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am using sass and compass for my project. However it provides a very cool mixins for i.e hacks.

For eg:

```
.display { @include inline-block; }
```

will execute

```
.display {  display: -moz-inline-stack;
   display: inline-block; 
   vertical-align: middle;
   *vertical-align: auto;
   zoom: 1;
   *display: inline;
}
```

But I want to separate all the ie hacks code to different css file such as `ie.css` and want it to place inside ie conditional comments, so that my css file would be w3c compatible.

Is there any idea to overcome this problem.. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the record, SASS's `@import` directive specifically does not include the code from a .css file into the SASS output.

Answer (score 1):

Just create two "parent" sass files. e.g. `screen.scss` & `ie.scss`
Put all of your actual sass into separate "child" scss files. 
Then in your "parent" files only have import statements.

EXAMPLE:

**SCREEN.SCSS**

```
//Global
@import "vars";
@import "mixins";

//Base
@import "reset";
@import "base";
@import "layout";    

//MODULES
@import "modules/module_a";
@import "modules/module_b";
```

**IE.SCSS**

```
@import "vars";
@import "mixins";
@import "ie_hacks";
```

This lets you import all of the sass dependant "child" files like any variable or mixins. It also lets you keep all the ie stuff in a separate css file. `ie.scss` is obviously going to be markedly smaller than your main `screen.scss`